# Add div with content inside another div on button click

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a simple dropdown and a checkbox as children of a div. I am trying to replicate this div when a user clicks on the "Add Another" button.

This is my div:

```
<div id="dominantDiv">
    <div id="childDiv">
        <div>
            Dominant Item
            @Html.CheckBox("checkbox", true, new { @onClick = "toggleSelect()" })
            @Html.Hidden("hidCheck")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("Drop", (IEnumerable
                           <SelectListItem>)TempData["Drop"], new { @id = "enableDrop", required = true })
            @Html.Hidden("hidSelection")
            <button type="button" id="addDominantBtn" onclick="addDominant()">Add Another</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've already tried using appendChild

```
function addDominant() {
        $("#dominantDiv").appendChild($("#childDiv"));
    }
```

to get the whole div and re-add it to its parent but I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendChild is not a function
    at addDominant
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Comment: Hi bl3Oct and welcome to SO. It seems you are mixing up jQuery and Vanilla JavaScript methods. `appendChild` is a DOM method. The jQuery variant is [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: thank you for the quick response @EmielZuurbier. I gave "append" a try but nothing gets appended. However, the errors have disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

And also, you need `clone` to create a new child element.

```
function addDominant() {
  $("#dominantDiv").append($("#childDiv").clone());
}
```

Comment: ```clone``` did the trick actually. Silly me, it's been quite a while since I've used javascript